# HTTP Request with Threading Python

Tags: python, multithreading, http, python-requests

I want to stream my video to my web browser using flask. So I follow the instructions in [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/).

In my program, while streaming my video, I have to make an HTTP request to another service.
While I make the request, my video stream is stopping.

My program is based on those link,
Please help how to use threading with lock and HTTP requests.

My sample code: *(the rest is the same with the source)*

```
def generate():
    global outputFrame, lock, isRecognized, cnt
    while True:
        # wait until the lock is acquired
        with lock:
            # check if the output frame is available, otherwise skip
            # the iteration of the loop
            cnt+=1
            if cnt%50 == 0:
                isRecognized = True
            if outputFrame is None:
                continue
            (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", outputFrame)
            # ensure the frame was successfully encoded
            if not flag:
                continue
        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')

def generate_car():
    # grab global references to the output frame and lock variables
    global isRecognized, outputFrame
    url = 'myurl.com'
    while True:
        # wait until the lock is acquired
        with lock:
            if isRecognized ==True:
                isRecognized = False
                # encode the frame in JPEG format
                cv2.imwrite("temp.jpg", outputFrame)
                with open("temp.jpg", "rb") as c:
                    b64string = base64.b64encode(c.read())
                    b64string=str(b64string)[2:-1]

                r = requests.post(url, data=b64string) # <-- this line is the problem

                r = json.loads(r.text)
                print('\n\n', r ,'\n\n')
                (__, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", outputFrame)
                # yield the output frame in the byte format
                yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + 
                    bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')
```

Comment: `print('\n\n', r ,'\n\n')` you don't seems to use value of r other than in print statement right? would it be okay for your program to defer printing and requesting to url in another thread or executor?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your flask app behind a web-server like nginx or by using uwsgi for it to process multiple requests concurrently.